# Add next and previous post links on pages like category, tags or archive pages

Tags: pagination, links, next

I am trying to find a solution for getting next pages for category or tag page in WordPress, tried with `next_posts_link` and `previous_posts_link` in these pages, but it's not working.

Same functions are working on post listing page for me

Below is my code

```
<div class="wrapper inner_content_wrap">


          <?php next_posts_link( '<span class="label iconfont"><img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/pager_arw.png" alt=""></span><span class="entry-info-wrap">Next Entries</span>',3); ?>
          <?php previous_posts_link( '<span class="label iconfont"><img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/pager_arw2.png" alt=""></span><span class="entry-info-wrap">previous Entries</span>'); ?>





        <div class="blog_area">
            <div class="container">

           <?php

             if(have_posts()) :
            $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
             $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'paged' => $paged );
             $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
             $i = '1';

             while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();  ?>
                  <?php if($i=='1' || $i%3 =='1') { echo '<div class="blog_post first">';}  else { echo '<div class="blog_post">';} ?> 
                        <div class="date"><?php the_time('M');  ?><strong><?php the_time('j'); ?></strong></div>                    
                        <div class="imgbox"> <?php  $url = get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'blog_thumb');
               echo $url; ?></div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">[...]</a></p>

                            <div class="bottom_box">
                                <?php $categories = get_the_category(); 
                                foreach($categories as $category) {
                                    echo '<a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'" class="button" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>';
                                    }?>



                                <div class="clear"><!-- --></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <?php 
            $i++; 
            endwhile; 
            else:
                get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

                endif;

            wp_reset_postdata();

 ?>


                <div class="clear"><!-- --></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Link to your site please. What theme are you using?

Comment: afaik, with your custom query, you won't get any category or tag specific posts. try and research http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts to set the posts per page to a different number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems I can see off hand here

Firstly, you should move your query to outside your `if` conditional statement.

Secondly, when using `WP_Query`, the `$max_pages` parameter should be used when using [`next_posts_link( $label , $max_pages );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link)

So, your code should look something like this

```
<div class="wrapper inner_content_wrap">

  <?php next_posts_link( '<span class="label iconfont"><img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/pager_arw.png" alt=""></span><span class="entry-info-wrap">Next Entries</span>', $loop->max_num_pages); ?>
  <?php previous_posts_link( '<span class="label iconfont"><img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/pager_arw2.png" alt=""></span><span class="entry-info-wrap">previous Entries</span>'); ?>

        <div class="blog_area">
            <div class="container">


<?php   
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'posts_per_page' => 3, 
    'paged' => $paged 
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );  

if($loop->have_posts()) :

    $i = '1';

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();  ?>

<-----REST OF YOUR CODE------->
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `get_next_posts_link();` right after or outside your while loop. So you'd use it something like:

```
<?php echo get_next_posts_link(); ?>
<?php echo get_previous_posts_link(); ?>
```

For more information:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_posts_link